# How to include maya 3D model to three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to include my 3D model to web page.How  to include Maya 3D model to three js?

Comment: http://blog.stickmanventures.com/2011/11/17/convert-a-model-from-maya-to-webgl-for-use-with-three-js/
Are you looked this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must export your model in `obj` format. Make sure you have `python 2.7` installed.

Then you can convert the `obj` to `js` format using the `python` script which is included in with `three.js` - `convert_obj_three.py`

Put both your model and the `python` script in the same folder as `python` to make it easier.

Then at the command line run:

```
python convert_obj_three.py -i infile.obj -o outfile.js
```

Where `infile.obj` is the name of your model you exported from maya, and `outfile.js` is the file you wish to load in `three.js`.

Once you have a converted file you can load it in with something similar to this script here, I'm creating 3 models but you can use it to load just one:

```
function loadModel() {
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("js/your_model.js", function( geometry ) {
    box = [];

    group = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add(group);

            // here i'm creating 3 objects of same model
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        box[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("js/your_texture.jpg")}));
        box[i].scale.set(20,20,20);
        box[i].position.x = (120*i) - 150;
        group.add(box[i]);
    }
        callSomeFunctionOnceLoaded();
        },"js"
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to load Materials dynamically from the Model itself?
I'm still finding difficulties including them in the exported model itself (From Blender) and Adding them to THREE dynamically from the model.

Answer (score -1):

I have just started to made a simple exporter to convert from OBJ to Three.JS version 3.1 JSON format. So if you dont want to use the python exporter you can use this one.

https://github.com/theMaxscriptGuy/Windows_Programs/tree/master/Obj_To_ThreeJS

Thanks